# Setting up nginx to support custom domain name

Tags: nginx, dns, webserver, cname

I have a Django web application hosted on a VM with the Debian-based Ubuntu as the OS, and nginx reverse proxy + gunicorn as the webserver.

The DNS of this web application is `myapp.cloudapp.net`. I also have a ccTLD `mydomain.pk` I need to be configured as a custom domain name for this web application.

My original registrar only supported nameservers. Thus I made an account on dns.he.net (a free DNS hosting provider) to host my nameservers, and set up the CName for my machine.

My problem is that once I set up the CName to point to my web app's DNS, entering mydomain.pk in the browser merely shows me a generic `Welcome to ngnix!` page. Whereas, entering `myapp.cloudapp.net` (or `myapp.cloudapp.net:80`) in the browser correctly opens up the web application. Why isn't setting up the CName working?

I've talked to the support staff at dns.he.net - I've been told my CName is set up correctly, and that there might be some problem with my nginx configuration.

For instance, here's my `etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.cloudapp.net;
    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/myuser/projectpk/project;
    }

    location /static/admin {

        root /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/projectpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/myuser/projectpk/project/project.sock;
    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/projectpk/project/templates/;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can remove the server_name line, it's not needed in nginx unless you want to serve different content depending on the host name you receive. If you remove that line, nginx will answer any request that arrives to your server at the proper port (80 in this case)

Comment: @tato: hmm okay will do, though since `myapp.cloudapp.net` works correctly, how does the `server_name` line mess up the forwarding when I set up a CName? Or is that not what you're implying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `server_name` line, it's not needed in nginx unless you want to serve different content depending on the host name you receive.

If you remove that line, nginx will answer any request that arrives to your server at the proper port (80 in this case), coming with `myapp.cloudapp.net` or `mydomain.pk` in the `Host` header.

This assumes that there is no other configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled that would catch the requests.

Comment: Ah no, this change gives me a generic `Welcome to nginx!` page even on `myapp.cloudapp.net` now.

Comment: do you have any other config file in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled dir? It might be getting the requests. Try removing the other one

Comment: The other file I have over there is `default`, that's probably the culprit. Let me get back to you, hold on.

Comment: remove it (it's probably a link to sites-available so it's safe to delete) or move it elsewhere

Comment: For completeness: the `sites-available` folder still has the `default` file in it. Does it matter if I let that remain?

Comment: `sites-available` can contain many files. Only those that are linked from `sites-enabled` will be read and used by nginx service.

Comment: but then, how can I configure ssl for that ?
Normally a server-name is needed ?