# custom domain in nginx (example.app) unable to connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Under the topic of LEMP stack, we were tasked to create/configure a website with the name "thething.app"

as with the guide provided from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04), I followed the configuration part on step 4.

The only difference would be that the site would have a php file instead of an html inside the web directory

```
<?php
    echo "this is thething.app";
?>
```

Here is my *(original)* configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thething.app www.thething.app;
    root /home/melonpan/thething.app;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

After activating my configuration by linking to the config file from Nginx’s sites-enabled directory  `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

I tested the syntax with `sudo nginx -t` which resulted in success, then I restarted nginx with `sudo systemctl reload nginx`

I then tried to go to thething.app on my browser, but it said "unable to connect"
[image: thething.app]

Fortunately I found this: [Setting up nginx to support custom domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834271/setting-up-nginx-to-support-custom-domain-name)

which had a similar problem.

So I removed the `server_name` line making my new configuration be

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/melonpan/thething.app;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

aftr re-linking, testing and restarting nginx, I thought that it would have worked. ***But no! It was still unable to connect.***

I even edited the host file  `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and added `127.0.1.1       thething.app`

*we're using ubuntu*

edit: I tried http://thething.app too, event disabling http only mode in firefox

***What am I doing wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

Add localhost as a server name and try accessing your app with that.

Make sure that the root attribute is pointing to a folder not a file and add a / to the end.

Also confirm that your PHP installation is working.

Comment: I have tried it, no luck still, the php is working too

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the IP address?

Comment: And make sure the URL does not say https, only http

Comment: I tried tirelessly to prevent Firefox from redirecting to https btw.

Comment: Assuming you don't have an add-on like HTTPS EVERYWHERE, you need to put http:// at the beginning AND :80 at the end in order for Firefox to not change it to https